# Allow screen saver while playing game?

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I’m on Windows 10 and set a screen saver to activate after 1 minute. I want this to activate even when I have Clone Hero open to protect my OLED screen. Most info online seems to be people having the opposite problem (unwanted screen saver activation during game). I’ve tried exclusive full screen, windowed full screen, and windowed settings. None allow the screen saver. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you lock your system while the game is playing the screensaver should then activated after 1 minute but how is Clone Hero a static persistent image?

Comment: My concern is about it being left on the menu for a while during a party, but I guess I’ll be able to notice that and can just turn the TV off myself. Thanks though!